# How to avoid page refresh in javascript function?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I used javascript function in my web page which is created using asp.net. I called the function on click event of the  tag. But in that page i 've handled other events to , and when i'm performing any event then that every time my page is reloaded freshly. I want to perform the java scrip function should be called when i'm clicking on the  tag.

I called the function as follows  in my html--

```
<a id="displayText" href="JavaScript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:toggle5('toggleText', 'displayText');">More</a>
```

my javascript function is --

```
function toggle5(showHideDiv, switchTag) {

           var ele = document.getElementById(showHideDiv);
           var imageEle = document.getElementById(switchTag);
           if (ele.style.display == "block") {
               ele.style.display = "none";
               imageEle.innerHTML = 'More'; //<img src="../images/more.JPG" style="height:18px;width:18px;border:none;">';
           }
           else {
               ele.style.display = "block";
               imageEle.innerHTML = 'Less'; //<img src="../images/less.JPG" style="height:18px;width:18px;border:none;">';
           }
   }
```

I am using above function for hiding below html tag---

```
<div id="toggleText" style="display:none;height:100%;width:100%;">
</div>
```

code which is performed in the click event--

```
protected void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBrought.Text = "";
        txtCall.Text = "";
        txtNoCall.Text = "";
        txtNoSales.Text = "";
        txtSearchData.Text = "";
        ddlMD.SelectedIndex = 0;
        ddlCEO.SelectedIndex = 0;
        ddlCRM.SelectedIndex = 0;
        ddlRH.SelectedIndex = 0;
        chkBrought.Checked = false;
        chkCall.Checked = false;
        chkInSalesPlan.Checked = false;
        chkNoCall.Checked = false;
        chkNoSales.Checked = false;
        chkOSPending.Checked = false;
        chkOutSalesPlan.Checked = false;
        txtBrought.Enabled =false;
        txtCall.Enabled = false;
        txtNoCall.Enabled = false;
        txtNoSales.Enabled = false;
    }
```

I placed the different asp.net controls in the  tag which i'm hiding using javascript function. I used the events of asp.net control. One of the control is asp.net button.

How to do this?

Comment: A demo or some code would be useful here!

Comment: can we see some of your code please?

Comment: When using anchors, you should return false in the href function to prevent a page reload

Comment: @Tom Knapen: i didn't get you. Can you explain little bit more?

Comment: Can you please place your code which calls onclick event?

Answer (score 0):

Well, i'm not sure of your problem but i've got a tip. I think your event is bubbling up, and so it causes to trigger the default event what for example an `<a>` tag would do, ergo: refresh. So u need to stop this bubbling up with:

```
$('a').bind('click', function(e){

  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  // CODE YOU WANNA DO

});
```

Comment: this is valid if you are using jQuery

Comment: well yeah, in the time of posting it, the question wanst detailed at all. Still i leave this, maybe somebody get some use of it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried above code and I don't get page refresh, Its working fine for me,

Browsers Tested: IE8,fireFox3

Comment: Have you used asp.net web site?

Comment: No. I tested in Plain HTML. If it works as plain HTML then It should work all the web technologies as finally HTML content is being parsed by browsers

Comment: problem of my script is that . When i'm executing any event then each time there is page refresh occurs & thats why it is calling my javascript function again. And i don't want to let this happen.

Comment: To Find out that, I need the whole HTML which browser got. Give me the URL if any which has this issue